# how to convert fetch to server action in nextjs

Tags: next.js13

I have this request payload for a mutation with a post method and am wondering if I'm trying to indicate a successful mutation with a toast, I should stick with fetch or work with a server action. One of the inconveniences of the server action is that each json property in an object like `{name, city, state, address, time, ...}` turns into an input field (imagine this is 20 fields):

```
          <form action={handleSave}>
            <input
              readOnly
              name="name"
              value={name}
            />
            <input
              readOnly
              name="city"
              value={city}
            />
            <input
              readOnly
              name="state"
              value={state}
            />
            <input
              readOnly
              name="address"
              value={address}
            />
            <input
              readOnly
              name="time"
              value={time}
            />
          </form>
```

and if I'm adding an entry while showing a toast, would an optimistic update be the way to go to prevent full reloads?